# Safe, idiomatic destroy-and-compact within fixed, unordered, owning array

Tags: c++, arrays, c++17, destructor, move-semantics

Consider a data structure containing a fixed-sized buffer that owns in-place members of some arbitrary nontrivial type. The buffer is unordered but its contents are stored contiguously using a fixed array and a counter value. What is the modern, idiomatic C++ way to destroy an element within that array, and replace its slot with the last element of the array to maintain continuity? I'm particularly concerned with making sure that the element is properly destructed and the replacement is properly and efficiently moved. Unfortunately, `std::vector` is not an option here.

Here's what I can think of offhand:

```
void destroy_replace(
    std::array<arbitrary, 20>& arr, 
    size_t& count,
    size_t index)
{
    SOME_ASSERT_MACRO(index < count);
    std::destroy_at(std::addressof(arr.at(index)));
    arr[index] = std::move(arr.at(count - 1));
    --count;
}
```

Is this correct? Especially the `std::destroy_at`?

Is the move necessary? Could/should I do this as a placement-new move constructor?

Is the order of operations correct with respect to exception guarantees?

Comment: How about `std:swap` last element with indexed one? Or rather `std::swap(last_elem, std::move(index_elem))`.  `index_elem` gets moved out (invalidated) and replaced by move with `last_elem`

Answer (score 1):

You should use placement new move constructor, as assignment operator of destroyed object is undefined. If you don't have such constructor, you can resort to default constructor, and then your move assignment, but the object after `std::destroy_at` should be constructed.

Move is needed to cast to rvalue reference, as `.at` result is lvalue reference.

Typical way to provide exception guarantee in this case is require move constructor or move assignment to be `noexcept`.  Otherwise it is not posible with moving, and you'll need to copy.

Comment: Do I have to worry about any alignment issues when performing a placement new in this array?

Comment: No, as long as you place values of the same type that you've passed as `std::array` template parameter, `std::array` will take care of it.

Answer (score 1):

Just move assign from the last element. It's not like your code is actually destroying anything on net (after it's fixed - you'd have to use placement new after destroying the element, so you destroy one and create another), and move assignment is usually at least as efficient - if not more - than destroy-and-reconstruct.

Comment: Say the arbitrary class contains a smart or raw pointer to data of some sort. Is it safe to expect a well behaved move assignment to prevent memory leaks in both the object we're moving from (which is now defunct/orphaned) and in the object we're clobbering by move-assigning into?

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches.  Either you move-assign over the element you want to delete, then destroy the last one, or *if* you have nothrow move construction you can destroy the one you want to delete, then move-construct over it, then move-destroy the last element.

```
template<class T, std::size_t N>
struct pseudo_array {
  using raw = std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(T), alignof(T)>;
  std::array<raw, N> data;
  std::size_t highwater = 0;
  void erase( std::size_t i ) {
    std::launder( (T*)(data.data()+i) )->~T();
    --highwater;
    if (i != highwater) {
       auto* ptr_last = std::launder(  (T*)(data.data()+highwater) );
       ::new( (void*)(data.data()+i) ) T( std::move(*ptr_last ) );
       ptr_last->~T();
    }
  }
  // add const version
  T& operator[](std::size_t i) {
    return *std::launder( (T*)(data.data()+i) );
  }
  std::size_t size() const { return highwater; }
  template<class...Args>
  T& emplace( Args&&...args ) {
    void* where = (void*)(data.data()+highwater);
    T* ptr_elem = ::new(where) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    ++highwater;
    return *ptr_elem;
  }
  // Care taken to keep invariants true while we destroy
  ~pseudo_array() {
    while(highwater > 0) {
      --highwater;
      std::launder( (T*)(data.data()+highwater) )->~T();
    }
  }
};
```

alternative erase:

```
 void erase( std::size_t i ) {
   auto* ptr_last = std::launder(  (T*)(data.data()+highwater-1) );
   auto* ptr_target = std::launder( (T*)(data.data()+i) );
   if (ptr_last!=ptr_target) {
     *ptr_target = std::move(*ptr_last);
   }
   --highwater; // this goes before dtor, in case dtor throws
   ptr_last->~T();
 }
```